# Cocos app does not creates Windows phone project

Tags: android, c++, ios, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a problem with Cocos2d-x for Mac. I need to create project for Android, iOS and Windows phone. I have downloaded Cocos app from [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download) and installed cocos2d-x v3.5 framework. And when I create project the wp8 project is missed, however I see win32 project, mac, iOS and Android project. Invoking this script also does not create wp8 solution:

```
cocos new -l cpp -p com.gamefromscratch.gamename -d ~/Documents/Projects/cocos2d gamename
```

So the question is how to create cocos2x project for Windows phone 8?
Do I nede Windows and visual studio to create this project, or I can do this on Mac?
 [image]

Comment: It is very easy to find out: read [the instructions for Windows Phone development](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/H/index.html).

Comment: So for Windows phone projects I need to install cocos2d-x on my Windows too? I mean I can't to do it on mac and then open on windows?

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem, only class and resource folder need to be synced. either use a repo or do a symbolic links to manage your project.